# Why 3d doesnt want ddtype?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science

when ı try to create a 2-D array using ndarray if I dont specify ddtype value it gives me error but when trying to create a 3-D one it doesn't why, I mean is there a rule like that?

```
import numpy as np
array=np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1,1,1,1]])


print(array)
print(array.ravel())
```

I receive the following error:

> c:/Users/fazil/Desktop/yeni metin belgesi.py:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray array=np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1,1,1,1]]) [list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) list([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])] [list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) list([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])]

Comment: Can you give an example of the erroring case, including the actual error?

Comment: @Random Davis  c:/Users/fazil/Desktop/yeni metin belgesi.py:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  array=np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1,1,1,1]])
[list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) list([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])]
[list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) list([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is telling you that the sublists differ in length, so it can't make a 2d numeric array.  In the future you will have to supply the `dtype`.  For now you just get the scolding.

```
In [217]: np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1,1,1,1]])
     ...: 
<ipython-input-217-a5da97fcce54>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1,1,1,1]])
Out[217]: 
array([list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), list([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])],
      dtype=object)
In [218]: x=np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1,1,1,1]], object)
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [219]: 
In [219]: x
Out[219]: 
array([list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), list([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])],
      dtype=object)
In [220]: len(x[0])
Out[220]: 6
In [221]: len(x[1])
Out[221]: 7
```

The warning has nothing to do with 2d versus 3d, or even the number of sublists.  If your other attempt works without the warning it must have equal length sublists.